# clojure: how to convert jdbc4array into clojure's seq?

Tags: postgresql, clojure, seq

I tried to query data from database with jdbc. The problem is some column is array type.

```
;get that particular column
(def jdbc-array (with-connection *db*                                                                    
                  (with-query-results rs ["select * from refgene limit 5"]                                        
                    (:exonstarts (first rs)))))

;Check if it has a value
(print jdbc-array)
;#<Jdbc4Array {67075873,67078739,67085754,67100417,67109640,67113051,67129424,67131499,67143471,67162932}>nil

;check class
(class jdbc-array)
;org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array
```

How to convert this array to seq/vector in clojure ?  I tried (seq jdbc-array) and (seq (.getArray jdbc-array) but both doesn't work...

Comment: The latter should work since `seq` is aware of arrays. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I got nil. It seems like getArray return empty array. There's api doc here but I don't understand it. http://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/jdbc4/Jdbc4Array.html.

Comment: The Jdbc4Array isn't actually an array, not does it support the Iterable interface. You'll need to convert it either into an array or something that supports Iterable first before seq will work.

Comment: any pointer ? I'm pretty new to java and clojure.

Comment: According to `java.sql.Array` the `.getArray` + `seq` combination should work. You can also try `.getResultSet` + `resultset-seq`. I suspect, that `.getArray` returns either an empty array or `nil`, because `seq` does not complain.

Answer (score 7):

If the with-connection option seems clunky to you (it does to me), you can extend the IResultSetReadColumn protocol to convert Jdbc4Array objects into regular or vectors:

Here's one way to do that:

```
(extend-protocol clojure.java.jdbc/IResultSetReadColumn
  org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array
  (result-set-read-column [pgobj metadata i]
    (vec (.getArray pgobj))))
```

this will convert all array types into vectors when reading

this approach can also help with the JSON datatype as in [this example](http://hiim.tv/clojure/2014/05/15/clojure-postgres-json/)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I got it. I need to called getArray before clojure close the connection, or it'll give a nil.

Not sure why... My guess is clojure's laziness.

```
;work
(with-connection *db*
  (with-query-results rs ["select * from refgene limit ?" 5]
    (seq (.getArray (:exonends (first rs))))))
```

Comment: Yes, unless you are fully processing the query results down to a simple value, you will run into the laziness of the resultset. Another workaround is using doall (with-query-results ... (doall (:exonends (first rs))))